# Is there an implicit conversion from std::shared_ptr<T> to std::shared_ptr<const T>?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, shared-ptr

Suppose I declare a function accepting an `std::shared_ptr<const T>` argument:

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<const T> ptr);
```

Will this function accept calls where a `std::shared_ptr<T>` is passed instead?

Comment: What happens if you try it? And whatever the result is, do you have a particular reason for thinking this result might not be a complete answer to your question?

Comment: No, it will not. Try not to use const casting, it is a bad practise. However, you can cast those std::shared_ptr using std::const_pointer_cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the constructors for [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), two of them are :

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r );  // (9)

template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y>&& r );       // (10)
```

which

> 9) Constructs a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership of the object managed by `r`. If `r` manages no object, `*this` manages no object too. This overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if `Y*` is not implicitly convertible to `T*`.
>
> 10) Move-constructs a `shared_ptr` from `r`. After the construction, `*this` contains a copy of the previous state of `r`, `r` is empty. This overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if `Y*` is not implicitly convertible to `T*`.

These constructors are not `explicit`, and `T*` is definitely implicitly convertible to `const T*`, that's just a qualification conversion. So yes, the function will accept it.  [**Simple Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2357e9e83f886c7)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass shared_ptr, but you will able to call only const methods:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<const A> val)
{
    val->ConstMethod();
    val->Method();      // Denied
}

//....
std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A());

foo(a);
```